# Meaning of cardinality of fuzzy sets & intuitionistic fuzzy sets

Tags: fuzzy-logic, fuzzy-set

We know that the cardinality of a finite crisp (or, classical) set $A$ can be considered as a measure of "number of elements" of $A$. However, if $X$ is a universe of discourse and $\tilde A$ (or, simply $A$) is a Fuzzy Set (FS) defined on $X$ such that
$$A=\{(x,\mu_A(x))\,:\,x\in X\}$$
where $\mu_A:X\to[0,1]$ is the membership function of the fuzzy set $A.$ Then the *scalar-cardinality* or the *sigma-count* ($\Sigma$*-count*) of the fuzzy set $A$ is defined as (see [here](https://www.mecs-press.org/ijisa/ijisa-v5-n6/IJISA-V5-N6-6.pdf)):
$$\lvert A\rvert=
\begin{cases} 
\displaystyle\sum_{x\in X} \mu_A(x),&\text{if }A\text{ is a discrete FS}
\\
\displaystyle\int_{x\in X} \mu_A(x)\,dx,&\text{if }A\text{ is a continuous FS.}
\end{cases}
$$
It is said to be an general extension of the notion of cardinality of a set!

My question is:

> What does it even mean in case of fuzzy sets?

(I mean we are just adding the membership grades of $x$!!)

Again, if $A$ is an Intuitionistic Fuzzy Set (IFS) on $X,$ $A$ is defined as:
$$A=\{(x,\mu_A(x),\nu_A(x))\,|\,x\in X\}$$
where $\mu_A(x)$ denotes the membership grade of $x$ in $A$ and $\nu_A(x)$ denotes the non-membership grade of $x$ in $A.$ Furthermore, both $\mu_A(x)$ and $\nu_A(x)$ lie in $[0,1]$ such that $0<\mu_A(x)+\nu_A(x)\le1,\forall x\in X.$

The *scalar-cardinality* or the $\Sigma$*-count* of the IFS $A$ is defined as (as can be seen [here](https://www.malayajournal.org/articles/MJM054.pdf)):
$$\Sigma\text{-count}(A)=\left[\sum_{x\in X}\mu_A(x),\sum_{x\in X}(1-\nu_A(x))\right].$$
Question:

> What does it signify?

---

Then there are Neutrosophic Set (NS) & Neutrosophic Fuzzy Set (NFS), which arise in Neutrosophy/Neutrosophic logic (e.g., see [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/324809354_Neutrosophic_Sets_An_Overview)), which can be considered as a generalization of an IFS.

Now, if $A$ is a Single Valued Neutrosophic Fuzzy Set (SVNFS) on $X,$ then
$$\text{SVNFS } A=\{\langle x,\mu_A(x),T_A(x),I_A(x),F_A(x)\rangle\,:\,x\in X\}$$
where all of $\mu_A,T_A,I_A$ and $F_A$ are functions from $X$ into $[0,1],$ and denote respectively the membership grade, the truth membership grade, the indeterminacy membership grade and the falsity membership grade of $x$ in $A.$ Moreover, $\mu_A(x),T_A(x),I_A(x)$ and $F_A(x)$ are independent measures for each $x\in X,$ and $0\le T_A(x)+I_A(x)+F_A(x)\le3,\forall x\in X.$

Question:

> Does the term *scalar-cardinality* make sense in case of SVNFSs as before? If yes, how could one define the same?

Please give some insights...

Comment: For fuzzy sets, you could think of $\mu_A(x)$ as a probability $P(x\in S_A)$. Then $|A|=E(|S_A|)$.

Comment: What did you mean by $S_A$?

Comment: A "random" non-fuzzy set modeled by $A$.

Comment: The idea is that a fuzzy set can "partially" or "probabilistically" contain an element instead of just definitely containing it or not. I don't think there's more "meaning" to it than that - it's just a mathematical structure.

Comment: Sir, I have understood what you wanted to imply to the best of my ability. Will you please comment on the scalar-cardinality/sigma-count of an IFS?

Comment: In [intuitionistic logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuitionistic_logic), we don't have the [law of excluded middle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_excluded_middle). So instead of having an exact probability for the fuzzy proposition $x\in S_A$, we have both a "truth amount" $\mu_A(x)$ and a "falsity amount" $\nu_A(x)$, which may add up to less than 1. If you think of these as defining the bounds $P(x\in S_A)\in[\mu_A(x),1-\nu_A(x)]$, then the scalar-cardinality of $A$ gives the resulting bounds on $E(|S_A|)$.

Comment: Certainly, the square brackets in the expression of the sigma-count of an IFS are meaningful if (& only if) I take into account your justification. Otherwise the expression, as defined, appears to be vague! Fortunately or unfortunately, the sigma-count of an SVNFS hasn't been defined yet. Sir, can we define the same somewhat like this: $|A|=(\sum_x \mu_A(x),\sum_x T_A(x),\sum_x I_A(x),\sum_x(1-F_A(x)))$? I used parentheses outside the expression because I'm not sure what else to use.